# Starting the email client doesn't include the attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
             new String[]
             {
                 "rundll32", 
                 "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler",
                 "mailto:a@a.de?subject=someSubject&cc=a@a.de&bcc=a@a.de&body=someBodyText&Attach=c:\\test\\test.doc"
              }, null
       );
} (IOException ri) {

}
```

I'm working on this code example which starts E-Mail client from Java application. I can successfully start the E-Mail client but I don't have any attachment. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Yes, use `JavaMail` instead for which you have already added the tag

Answer (score 0):

Starting the mail client by a `mailto:` link and passing the filename for an attachement is a high security risk and thus prohibited by the most MUA. Allowing such thing would mean that you are able to craft a URL which then will offer the user to actively send you any file from his harddisk. *Absolutely a no-go*.

You must integrate with the APIs offered by the underlying OS. You can not use `mailto:` links for a sophisticated  task like this